# using passport-azure-ad configuration to secure a web app and web server via OIDCStrategy and BearerStrategy

Tags: javascript, azure, express, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I have a web app that is provided by an express.js server (web app server). The web app server handles the user login via passport.js and the passport-azure-ad npm package. I am using the **OIDCStrategy** for this.

I am also hosting a REST api via another server (rest backend). I want to secure this backend via passport.js and the passport-azure-ad npm package using the **BearerStrategy**. For that I want to define a scope in the web app server passport configuration so that the access_token of the web app server can be passed via a cookie to my web app and from there be used to access the rest backend.

My issue: with my current configuration, I receive 401 access denied while trying to access my backend api with the access_token. `access_token invalid` is the error message: `{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy", "msg":"authentication failed due to: error: invalid_token","v":0}`

I think I should be redirected to a permission page while signing in but it does not. So I guess my access token is actually not valid.

Web app server passport configuration:

```
passport.use(
  new OIDCStrategy(
    {
      clientID: credsAzureAD.clientID,
      identityMetadata: credsAzureAD.identityMetadata, // here is use the web app tenant id
      clientSecret: credsAzureAD.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: credsAzureAD.returnURL,
      redirectUrl: credsAzureAD.returnURL,
      skipUserProfile: true,
      responseType: 'code',
      responseMode: 'query',
      scope: 'api://test/Write.Contributor',
      useCookieInsteadOfSession: false,
      passReqToCallback: false
    },
    (issuer, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
        user.accessToken = accessToken;
        return done(null, user);
    }
  )
);
```

I try to use the scope where `api://test` is my REST API application ID uri and `/Write.Contributor` is the scope that I defined in azure active directory.

My REST backend server passport configuration:

```
const options = {
    identityMetadata: azureAD.identityMetadata, // here I use the backend server tenant id
    clientID: azureAD.clientID,
    issuer: azureAD.issuer, // here I use the backend server tenant id
    passReqToCallback: false,
};

const bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(options, function(token, done) {
    done(null, {}, token);
});
```

I have created my backend server in azure active directory via application registration and created the named scope and application id above. I also have whitelisted my web app clientId there as a authorized client applications.

I try to call following route and receive 401:

```
app.get(
    '/testtest',
    cors(),
    passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var claims = req.authInfo;
        console.log('User info: ', req.user);
        console.log('Validated claims: ', claims);
        res.status(200).json({ name: claims['name'] });
    }
);
```

This is my rest call from my vue web app:

```
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${this.user.accessToken}`,
      'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    };
    const apiClient = axios.create({
      baseURL,
      headers
    });
    apiClient.get('/testtest').then( resp => console.log( resp));
```

I am taken the access token as is no decoding/encoding.

Any support would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you Added your backend AD application scope in the client application via Azure Portal? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the scope and I know receive another error message. `authentication failed due to: error: invalid_token, error description: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: Invalid JWT token.` so I guess I have to figure that out now. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my question, and added how I am using the accessToken. Am I using the wrong access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jim Xu suggested in the comments, adding the application scope of the REST api to the client application via Azure Portal helped solving the issue. But I was also using the wrong token.

instead of using the `accessToken` from the verify function parameter list, I now use the `param` from the verify function parameter list.

```
(iss, sub, profile, access_token, refresh_token, params, done) => {
     // access_token did not work
     // id_token can be used as an accessToken
     user.accessToken = params.id_token;
     ...
}
```